# Factory create model is not empty Magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model, factory

I use a custom model with it's own Factory.

In my helper in the construct

```
public function __construct(

\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Communication\CollectionFactory $communicationFactory
){

$this->_communicationFactory = $communicationFactory;

return parent::__construct($context);

  }
```

I created the first registry and saved it with

```
$communication = $this->_communicationFactory->create();
```

And after adding some data

```
$communication->save();
```

By the time I created the first one, there was no problem, everything ok.
But when I try to create another one the instance of the model has already loaded the data from the first one, and I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Company\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Communication\Collection::setStatus() in /Users/Username/projects/htdocs/example.com/htdocs/extensions/company/module-modulename/Helper/Data.php:414
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: can you please paste your entire `helper` code for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by changing the path in the construct

This is how it should be done:

```
\Company\ModuleName\Model\CommunicationFactory                          $communicationFactory,
```

Before I was getting a instance of the collection, now I'm getting an instance of the single object.